# Avoid for loop for setting the matrix element in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

In a matrix, how does one set an adjacent and diagonal element to 1 if the values in these locations are the same avoiding a for loop? 
 An attempt made with for loop is given

```
[r,c] = size(mat1);
Sval = zeros(size(mat1));
for i = 1:r
    for j = 1:c-1
        if(mat1(i,j) == mat1(i,j+1))
            Sval(i,j) = 1;
            Sval(i,j+1) = 1;
        else
            Sval(i,j) = 0;
            Sval(i,j+1) = 0;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: In a matrix, how do you define what is "adjacent"?  Instead of showing us code, can you provide an example of the expected inputs and outputs?

Answer (score 0):

To receive the exact same output without the loops the code is the following. However it is not quite clear what you want to achieve with this code. Please elaborate further if this doesn't answer your question.

```
Sval = mat1(:,1:c-1) == mat1(:,2:c);
Sval(:,c) = Sval(:,c-1);
```

If I interpret your sentence right what you actually want is to shift/copy the equal values to the right as well. This could be achived by:

```
Sval = mat1(:,1:c-1) == mat1(:,2:c);
Sval(:,c) = zeros(r,1);
Sval(:,2:c) = Sval(:,1:c-1) | Sval(:,2:c);
```